# unable to excute command without sudo root

Tags: ansible

remote user:ab
escalated user: UNIX

when i am doing copy module to /etc/profile.d/.its throwing error permission denied.
but with shell and command module.

```
sudo  cp    myscript.sh    /etc/profile.d/
```

its working from UNIX user.i want to use ansible module rather than shell or command.here issue with sudo from UNIX user to execute command with sudo privileged.Become user i can't use root directly. Dont have access through unix user i can use sudo.

already used below details.

```
become=yes
become_method=sudo
become_user=unix
become_ask_pass=false
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo cp` means that it is running as root, not the user unix.

Try removing the line

`become_user=unix`

Comment: Don't have access to become root. Have to go through unix user. Unix user have access to run command with sudo

Comment: Sudo runs a command as root, so if you are using sudo you have root access.

Are you running the playbook as user unix or someone else?  If you are running the playbook as user unix, then become=yes will tell the playbook to become root and run the copy play as root